# Call multiple IO functions on the same input

Tags: haskell, io, applicative

Suppose I have a list of tuples (e.g. `[(a,b)]`) each a result of some previous computation.

And I want several functions to be applied on each of these elements (e.g one function might print it another send it over the network etc.)

What I've tried:

```
import Control.Applicative
main = do
          let a = [1..5]
          let fs = [(\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k*2), (\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k-2), (\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k*10)]
          let res = fs <*> a 
          putStrLn $ "Yo"
```

prints just `"Yo"`.

Comment: there is a shortcut `putStrLn . show == print`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely `res` has type `[IO ()]` and you never use it.

So just `sequence` it:

```
main = do
  let a = [1..5]
  let fs = [(\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k*2), (\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k-2), (\k-> putStrLn $ show $ k*10)]
  let res = fs <*> a
  sequence res
  putStrLn $ "Yo"
```

---

in case you want to know how you could right the complete block more concise than you could refactor the list of mappings (using *sections*), go with `print` (which is basically your `putStrLn . show`) and `mapM_`:

```
main = do
  mapM_ print $ [(* 2), (+ (-2)), (* 10)] <*> [1..5]
  putStrLn $ "Yo"
```

which will give

```
λ> :main
2
4
6
8
10
-1
0
1
2
3
10
20
30
40
50
Yo
```

as well ;)

---

note that you probably should not mix all the `IO` stuff with the purer computations - instead I would refactor the list of integers out:

```
myCombinations :: [Int] -> [Int]
myCombinations ns = [(* 2), (+ (-2)), (* 10)] <*> ns

main = do
  mapM_ print $ myCombinations [1..5]
  putStrLn $ "Yo"
```

(of course introducing functions as you go along, but I cannot guess what you are trying to achieve here)

from this you gain the ability to just check your pure functions/values:

```
λ> myCombinations [1..5]
[2,4,6,8,10,-1,0,1,2,3,10,20,30,40,50]
```

and gain probably a lot of readability ;)

Comment: Is there some more concise or 'Haskelish' form to write this (possibly as a whole and not just the sequencing assuming the list of results is actually a return value of some `foo`)?

Comment: I think [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) **is** just this (if you have your list  `actions :: [IO foo]`s then `sequence actions :: IO [foo]` so you will get a list with your `foo`s - of course you would want to use it like `foos <- sequence actions` inside `main`s do block then)

Comment: @GeorgeNi I have added another version are you talking about this?

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I was hoping for!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of `ios :: [a -> IO b]` you could use `mapM ($ aValue) ios` to get `IO [b]` or `mapM_` to get `IO ()`

Answer (score 0):

`let` doesn't bind anything into the monad. So `IO` doesn't care what you do with `<*>` to apply functions in a list, as long as you don't use the result in any way in a monad action.

To simply execute a list of actions in... well, *sequence*, you can use `sequence`:

```
    let res = fs <*> a
    sequence res
```